# Appending a sequence of numbers to an existing vector

Tags: r

I can't get R to append a sequence of numbers to an existing vector. Here's what I'm trying. The `cat` lines are for debugging.

```
#Make a vector 900 elements long that contains 1-100 9 times each
vec <- NA
for(i in 1:100) {
    cat("i = ", i, "\n")
    cat("sequence to be appended: ", rep(i, 9), "\n")
    vec < - c(vec, rep(i, 9))
    cat("new vector value: ", vec, "\n")
}
```

This works but is a more awkward way of doing it:

```
vec <- NA
for(i in 1:100) {
    vec[(i*9-8):(i*9)] <- i
}
vec
```

What's wrong with the first way? Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo at `< -`. There is a gap in between and that is why it does not work. If you fix this it works. Also, using `NA` to initiate the `vec` variable doesn't seem to be what you want to do. You probably needed `c()` there otherwise the first element would be `NA`.

Comment: Also, use `rep(1:100, each=9)`.  Growing vectors is a really bad idea.

Comment: Btw, you should rather try initializing your vector with a length `0` like: `x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, really should be `x <- numeric(900)` so vector doesn't need to be grown.

Comment: if you changed it to `vec <- NULL` it would work but as others have said, there are better ways of doing it

Comment: Thanks and sorry about the typo. Got some good tips here, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  vec<-rep(1:100, each=9)
```

is the way to do this

But if you ask what was wrong with your statement, it should be:

```
 vec <- rep(1, 9)
 for(i in 2:100) {
 vec <- c(vec,rep(i, 9))
 }
```

So drop the vec<-NA and take the first iteration out the loop, this will work also